# How to orderby multiple meta fields with another meta query

Tags: query, meta-query

I have a custom post type ”events” with meta fields ”startdate” and ”enddate”. Archive query already uses meta query to show only upcoming or ongoing events, but in addition I need to order by both meta fields. I can't figure out what the meta query should be, so it works for both uses. Or am I doing something wrong?

This is part of the query, with the simple orderby that I need to replace. Anyone got any ideas how to add ”...orderby startdate, enddate” to this?

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'enddate' => array (
        'key' => 'enddate',
        'value' => date( 'Y-m-d' ),
        'compare' => '>='
    ),
    'startdate' => array (
        'key' => 'startdate',
        'value' => date( 'Y-m-d' ),
        'compare' => '>=',
    )
);
$query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');   
$query->set('meta_key', 'startdate');
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE!  There may need to be some more context to your question. One thing that I would question is the format of the data. You'll have a hard time with querying (if >=) and sorting as a date because meta data is a string - it's never formatted as a date.  One way around that is to store post meta that are dates using Unix epoch time (because that can be sorted as a string). Just a suggestion to look into.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The format is `yyyy-mm-dd` which might not be the best way to store dates, but it worked fine before migrating the data into Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You've already named the clauses in your meta query, so you can reference these directly in the `orderby` argument:

```
$query->set(
    'orderby',
    array(
        'enddate' => 'DESC',
        'startdate' => 'DESC'
    )
);
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. I've printed out the query, but I'm not a database expert:

`SELECT   posts.* FROM posts  INNER JOIN postmeta ON ( posts.ID = postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ( 
    ( postmeta.meta_key = 'startdate' AND postmeta.meta_value >= '2018-11-23' ) 
    OR 
    ( postmeta.meta_key = 'enddate' AND postmeta.meta_value >= '2018-11-23' )
  )
) AND posts.post_type = 'event' GROUP BY posts.ID ORDER BY postmeta.meta_value ASC, CAST(postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) ASC`

Comment: I'm trying to achieve order where the events are ordered first by startdate, and when it matches with another, the event with the earlier (or empty) enddate would come first.

Comment: With this orderby, matching startdates are messed up. Additionally, all the startdates are not in order either. Seems like black magic to me, compared to a simple clause in good old mysql :)

Comment: ah, because your relationship is an `OR`,  it can match posts that have one key or the other, but not necessarily both. I guess you have to make both keys required to order by both.